# How to change the default jquery mobile loading icon

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

No matter what custom icon I change my ajax-loading too (with a transparent background), the actual loading animation looks all messed up and seems to have a black background.

How can I resolve?

Using JQuery Mobile 1.4.2n on PhoneGap 3.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery mobile defines the background-color property on the css selector ".ui-loader .ui-icon-loading" along with the background property on the css selector ".ui-icon-loading".

Something like this -

**Default CSS already present in jQuery Mobile -**

```
.ui-loader .ui-icon-loading {
  background-color: #000; 
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 2.75em;
  height: 2.75em;
  padding: .0625em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2.25em;
  border-radius: 2.25em;
}

.ui-icon-loading {
  background: url(images/ajax-loader.gif);
  background-size: 2.875em 2.875em;
 }
```

So even if you change the background properly using css selector ".ui-icon-loading" & use a transparent gif, the background-color: #000 will also get applied to your loading block.

You can fix this & get rid of the black background by **overriding the default CSS properly**, just make sure your custom css file comes after the default jquery mobile css file -

**Method 1 (By Overriding default loader CSS)**

Add the following to your custom css file -

```
.ui-loader .ui-icon-loading {
   background-color: transparent;
 }
 .ui-icon-loading {
   background: url("url_to_your_custom_loader.gif");
  }
```

This method will lawfully override both the default definitions and use the new loader.

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nitishdhar/bWMhV/

Note:- I have also overridden the border radius in the fiddle just because the loader I used was not supposed to have border.

**Method 2 (By Overriding default loader CSS)**

Add the following to your custom css file -

```
.ui-loader .ui-icon-loading {
   background: url("url_to_your_custom_loader.gif");
 }
```

Defining just background to the top selector will only follow this background definition on the loading class & will ignore any defined background color.

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nitishdhar/bWMhV/1/

Also note you can also override the width, height, padding etc to accommodate your new loader gif.

**Method 3 (Without Overriding default loader CSS)**

You can also use any custom loader image or content by utilizing the "html" option in the loader show method, just pass any HTML to the html option while calling the loader show & it will not use the default loader instead will use your provided html.

Ref this - http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/loader/#CustomHTML

Look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nitishdhar/bWMhV/2/

Comment: I've done this and the spinner still appears with a black background

Comment: Can you create a fiddle using your code so I can see whats going wrong.

Comment: I tried this and I still get a black background in my app. I think it has something to do with phonegap...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the selected answer really works...just make sure to try and put .ui-loader .ui-icon-loading {
   background-color: transparent !important;

After adding !important and the code above it finally got rid of the persistent black block behind the loading icon.